# How can i communicate Android device with using com port?

Tags: android, qt, qtserialport, qtandroidextras

I am working on Android project using Qt and i need to communicate between mobile phone and computer. I want to make little demo with using Putty.I want to send data mobile phone over USB cable and display on Putty to ensure communication. When i search Serial port on mobile phone  `const QList<QSerialPortInfo> &info = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();`  `info.count()` is equal zero. Application can not find any serial port on mobile phone but i can send or receive data (drag and drop) over USB cable. How can i communicate to Android device with using Serial Port?

Thank you for answers..

Comment: If you can use Bluetooth or WiFi (Ethernet) then is more simple. As Marcos G. mentioned not all phones supporting USB Serial cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered what i did wrong. The phone does not support OTG feature, so i could not see serial port by using qt serialport library. If anyone faces this problem, i hope this works for him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Not many mobile phones that come with a native serial port as far as I know.

If what you mean is you have a USB serial port connected to your mobile phone through an OTG cable maybe you need to take a look [here](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android). There is also an app on the Play Store based on the same code.